password visibility toggle in jetpack compose
I'm trying to implement a visibility toggle in jetpack, however the password is visible right after I click the button even before the authentication
var isAuthenticated by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    } 
var show_pass by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }


IconButton(onClick = {
                        if (!isAuthenticated){
                            promptManager.showBiometricPrompt("Authentication required", "Confirm it's you!")
                            if (biometricResult is BiometricResult.AuthenticationSuccess) {
                                isAuthenticated = true
                                show_pass = true
                            }
                            else{
                                isAuthenticated = false
                                show_pass = false
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            isAuthenticated = false
                            show_pass = false
                        }
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = if (show_pass) R.drawable.eye_alt_svgrepo_com else R.drawable.eye_slash_alt_svgrepo_com),
                            contentDescription = null, modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                        )
                    }



You need to apply a "visualTransform" to your password field.
val visualTransformation = if (show_pass) {
    VisualTransformation.None
} else {
    PasswordVisualTransformation()
}

Jetpack Compose already provides PasswordVisualTransform  so there's no need implementing it yourself.
Then apply it like the following:
OutlinedTextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
    singleLine = true,
    trailingIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = { show_pass = !show_pass }) {
            Image(
                imageVector = visibility,
                contentDescription = contentDescription,
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(visibilityColor)
            )
        }
    }


the reason I'm applying the transformation manually is because I want to first authenticate the user using their biometrics/password, then show them the password

Then all you need to do is adjust the example to your code. Make sure the transform is changed as soon as show_pass is toggled and you should be fine. Try to debug whenever show_pass changes and make sure your field behaves as expected.

OutlinedSecureTextField is designed for password field (available since material3 1.4.0).
